# How to stop popup from hiding behind embedded object in IE

Tags: jsf, popup, richfaces, embed

To reproduce the problem move pupup in front of pdf and try to resize it. In IE (tested on 8 and 9) popup partialy hides behind pdf. In Firefox and Chrome everything is ok.

```
<h:body>
        <h:form>
            <iframe id="overviewFrame" src="http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/pdf/richfaces_reference.pdf" width="900" height="800" />          
            <h:commandButton value="openPopupWithPdf">
                <rich:componentControl target="pdfPopup" operation="show" />
            </h:commandButton>
        </h:form>
        <h:form>
            <rich:popupPanel autosized="false" id="pdfPopup" resizeable="true" width="300" height="100" moveable="true" overlapEmbedObjects="true">
                <f:facet name="controls">
                    <a4j:commandLink id="documentHideEditLink" styleClass="hidelink" onclick="#{rich:component('pdfPopup')}.hide()" execute="@this">
                        <h:graphicImage value="/img/modal/close.png" />
                    </a4j:commandLink>
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    This is popup header
                </f:facet>   
                <h:panelGrid>
                    Some text
                </h:panelGrid>
            </rich:popupPanel>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
```

Same thing if I use a4j:mediaOutput instead of iframe.

Comment: do you have `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">` in your page?

Comment: Yes I have doctype declaration @Daniel.